# sed search and replace creating new file

Tags: sed, cygwin

I'm trying to search and replace some text within a file.  I'd be fine with either creating a new file, or overwriting the existing file.

If I use

```
sed -i 's/<texttoreplace>/<newtext>/g' foo.txt
```

I end up with two files:

**foo.txt** is the modified file
**foo.txte** is the original

If I use

```
 sed -i 's/<texttoreplace>/<newtext>/g' foo.txt > bar.txt
```

I end up with 2 files:

**foo.txt** is the original unmodified file.
**bar.txt** is 0 bytes.

What am I doing wrong? I'd really prefer to just overwrite the original file in place, which certainly seems like it should be possible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To make your second example work, where you explicitly want to create a second file, simply drop the `-i` flag.

```bash
sed 's/<texttoreplace>/<newtext>/g' foo.txt > bar.txt
```

Your first example is a bit of a head-scratcher.  The `-i` flag performs the editing in place, with an optional backup file of the original contents.  It works fine for me, without the creation of a '.txte' file.  You might get it to work by explicitly telling it no extension, using the syntax below:

```bash
sed -i'' 's/<texttoreplace>/<newtext>/g' foo.txt
```

You shouldn't have to do that, but maybe there is something in your environment different from mine.

Comment: The redirect without the -i works perfectly now.  The txte file was a goof on my part.  I had `sed -ie ...`, which resulted in foo.txte.

Answer (score 2):

I was using `sed -ie` on my mac, which was doing the same thing creating a backup file from origin and adding `e` at the end of file extension. Using `gsed -i` didn't complain about it and changed the file without creating a backup file.

To install gnu sed using brew:

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed -i ''` will not create another file as backup

Answer (score 1):

just copy and do sed

```
# docker can not replace mount file
cp /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
sed -i "s/findText/${replaceText}/g" /etc/nginx/conf.d/dboard_nginx.conf
```